# Making a mouse button trigger a class event

Tags: java, swing

I am really struggling with making a program that has buttons on it and when a button is clicked, it calls a class to work.  I have only been using Java for about 10 weeks now and I get the basics but I have not found any place that gives me an understanding of what I want to do here.

I have tried

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

                 if (e.getButton()== MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
                       Object triangle;
                       Frame.class.getClass();
                 }

          }
```

I have also tried

```
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
if (e.getButton()== MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
    Frame.class.getClass(circle); }
```

Either way I have tried it I usually get an error unable to find object or The method `getClass()` in the type `Object`is not applicable for the arguments (`JButton`).

Can anyone please help me try to figure out what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: If I had a problem like this, the first place I'd look would be the tutorials, specifically the [JButton tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). Surely you've done this right, and you've seen that you shouldn't be using a MouseListener at all, but instead adding an ActionListener to your JButton.

Comment: I get how to use a JButton ActionListener instead of a MouseEvent also.  I only went for a MouseEvent Listener because a friend said that is what I should be trying.  I know I can use something like class Listener implements ActionListener{ public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  and then some sort of if this button is clicked, do this.  I still do not know how to make the action do a class that I have created in a different file.

Comment: Then you should pick up your basic OO programming book, since _do a class that I have created in a different file_ sounds like you are lacking some basic Java/OO knowledge in the first place

Comment: Then perhaps you will want to describe in greater detail just what it is you are trying to do. What user event are you wanting to react to? pressing a button? clicking on a JPanel? something else? and what action do you want this event to stimulate? Can you show more code of what you've tried and greater detail on just what errors  you see?

Comment: I am just trying to create a simple JFrame with 3 JButtons, once a button is clicked, I have a sepearte class in another file that should work when that button is clicked, creating a circle or a triangle or a rectangle on the screen.  I have no problem putting these together and running it and making them all appear at the same time, I need however to allow the user to click the button and then execute the class for each independently.  I have struggled with the action listeners for a while now.  I get how to make it do a string but not perform a class.

Comment: @user1350056: since your code involves only clicking buttons and not clicking JPanels, trust me -- ignore your friend or whomever told you to use a MouseListener because they are just plain wrong. Use an ActionListener as has been suggested by me and others.

Comment: What **exactly** is a  `Frame`? Is it a `java.awt.Frame` or something else?  Note that to operate methods of the frame, you need a reference to an instance of it,rather than a `Frame` class.  I thik that is what @Robin was alluding to, and it is something that should be figured out ***long*** before starting GUI programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private JButton button = new JButton("Run AnotherClass");

MainFrame() {
    super();
    this.setTitle("Demo App");
    this.setSize(200,200);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
}

public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {      
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new AnotherClass();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
}
```

}

```
public class AnotherClass {
public AnotherClass()   {       
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "AnotherClass is in operation");
}
```

}